# CSS different padding and margin does a different pc (x32 vs. x64 ) can be the cause?

Tags: css, padding

I notice a strange problem with the padding of a Wordpress theme i am developing. In FF/Chrom/IE8 on my own pc everything is ok.

Client has two different pc's but with the same IE8 browser. On each pc the div padding on one page is different. Unfortunatly, can't recreate the issue on me own pc. But what could be the cause???

Any tips, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

check that the IE is not running in comapatibility mode on one system. This is indicated by a little broken page icon in the address bar.

Compatibility view is likely to break standards compliant styling, as it tries to emulate ie7 rendering.